# Extract common config elements into a shared file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, config

We have hundreds of config files across many applications and would like to consolidate the common elements in a global config file. Is there an existing tool out there that could do this? We looked at diff checkers, but this requires manual work on our part which is prone to errors.

Comment: The configuration files are XML and using XML Linq Net Library can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `XmlDocument` with great success in the past. You will need to keep merging each file into the main document one at a time using a 1-off C# console app. Once they are all merged, write the document OuterXml property to a new file.

With `XmlDocument` you can add new nodes and elements dynamically. If all your config files have unique elements, then there is not any merging you need to do. If there are overlaps or duplicates, you'll have to decide on rules as to what wins or whether you allow duplicate elements.